# SFX with 7-zip : Is it possible to run a included .bat file *before* extracting the files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip, sfx

I'm creating a [SFX executable](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm) with 7-zip (command line version) and the [7zsd.sfx](http://7zsfx.info/en/) module. My current config file looks like this :

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="Test"
BeginPrompt="Test"
CancelPrompt="Do you want to cancel the extraction?"
ExtractDialogText="Please, wait..."
ExtractPathText="Please, enter the extraction path:"
ExtractTitle="Extracting..."
GUIFlags="8+32+64+256+4096"
GUIMode="1"
InstallPath="%%S"
RunProgram="test2.bat"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

Is it possible to run a program *before* extracting the files? Currently, `test2.bat` is ran once the files are extracted. I'd like :

- The user click "OK"
- `test1.bat` is executed
- Files are extracted
- `test2.bat` is executed

Using WinRAR's SFX, there is a `presetup` option. Is there something similar using 7-zip and 7zsd.sfx?

Comment: I know this is an ancient post, but I have been looking SFXs today.  Where did you find documentation on any of those items in the config file?  The link you provided only has Title, BeginPrompt, etc.  No ExtractPathText, IstallPath, GUIMode, etc.

Answer (score 3):

One workaround I found is to extract the files to a temporary folder instead of the final target, run the first `.bat` file, xcopy the temp folder to the real target and finally run the last `.bat`.